# How to use chrome API in React.js Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I've developed a React app that acts as a Chrome Extension (the production index.html becomes the `default_popup` html page in the Chrome Extension `manifest.json`)

However, I need to access the chrome API and I'm unable to use it in my react app as the app is neither a background.js nor a content script. What would I need to do in order to make my React app able to access the Chrome API?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best solution, but it's one of the solutions: you can finish the react project with build command and use only the build folder as chrome extension:

after you finished the UI (react part) do :

```
npm run build
```

go to build folder and change the **manifest.json** to something like this:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "short_name": "React App",
 "name": "Create React App Sample",
 "description": "google chrome  extension",
 "version": "1.0",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
 "default_popup": "index.html"
 },
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
 "permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
 "start_url": ".",
 "display": "standalone",
 "theme_color": "#000000",
 "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

the final result should look like this:
[image]

In the **background.js** you can do anything you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong if you think that a popup page can't use Chrome API. Popup pages run in the same context as background scripts, and therefore have the same access to Chrome API. So if your extension is only supposed to consist of popup page, you can call Chrome API directly from your popup.

However, if you suppose to also use background and/or content script(s) and build all these extension components within the same build process, you have to modify CRA's build configuration to make it support multiple entry points and other things needed for extensions. Fortunately, there is a custom CRA template - [`complex-browserext`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-complex-browserext) that does all the customization needed for chrome extensions.